# Jolt List Transformation

Tags: json, list, jolt

I am trying to transform a JSON using jolt without adding new items as well as remove white space from the key value. additionally, I would like to know how to get map to current list.

**input** :

```json
[
  {
    "id": "9164339966213408050",
    "actualEndDate": "2022-08-15T14:47:09+03:00",
    "extendedChars": [
      {
        "Total BYOP Tier": {
          "values": [
            {
              "value": "60"
            }
          ],
          "name": "Total BYOP Tier",
          "isMultiple": false,
          "tomsId": "9162933742365468326"
        }
      }
    ],
    "chars": {
      "Total BYOP Tier": "60"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "9164339966213408051",
    "actualEndDate": "2022-08-15T14:47:09+03:00",
    "extendedChars": [
      {
        "Total BYOP Tier": {
          "values": [
            {
              "value": "60"
            }
          ],
          "name": "Total BYOP Tier",
          "isMultiple": false,
          "tomsId": "9162933742365468325"
        }
      }
    ],
    "chars": {
      "Total BYOP Tier": "60"
    }
  }
]
```

**expected output** :

```json
[
  {
    "id": "9164339966213408050",
    "actualEndDate": "2022-08-15T14:47:09+03:00",
    "extendedChars": [
      {
        "values": [
          {
            "value": "60"
          }
        ],
        "name": "Total BYOP Tier",
        "isMultiple": false,
        "tomsId": "9162933742365468326",
        "TotalBYOPTier": {
          "values": [
            {
              "value": "60"
            }
          ],
          "name": "Total BYOP Tier",
          "isMultiple": false,
          "tomsId": "9162933742365468326"
        }
      }
    ],
    "chars": {
      "TotalBYOPTier": "60"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "9164339966213408051",
    "actualEndDate": "2022-08-15T14:47:09+03:00",
    "extendedChars": [
      {
        "values": [
          {
            "value": "60"
          }
        ],
        "name": "Total BYOP Tier",
        "isMultiple": false,
        "tomsId": "9162933742365468325",
        "TotalBYOPTier": {
          "values": [
            {
              "value": "60"
            }
          ],
          "name": "Total BYOP Tier",
          "isMultiple": false,
          "tomsId": "9162933742365468325"
        }
      }
    ],
    "chars": {
      "TotalBYOPTier": "60"
    }
  }
]
```

**spec** tried :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "CustomerProductArray"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "CustomerProductArray": {
        "*": {
          "extendedChars": {
            "*": {
              "* * *": "CustomerProductArray.&(0,1)&(0,2)&(0,3)",
              "*": {
                "name": "CustomerProductArray[].extendedChars[]..name",
                "isMultiple": "CustomerProductArray[].extendedChars[].isMultiple",
                "tomsId": "CustomerProductArray[].extendedChars[].tomsId",
                "values": "CustomerProductArray[].extendedChars[].values"
              }
            }
          },
          "chars": {
            "* * *": "CustomerProductArray[].chars.&(0,1)&(0,2)&(0,3)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below spec as you want to replicate the content of the **`Total BYOP Tier`** array, nested inside and outside the object

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&1.&",
        "extendedChars": {
          "*": {
            "Total BYOP Tier": {
              "*": {
                "@": "&5.&4[&3].&" // &5 : (going up the tree five levels) replicates the index of the outermost array, &4[&3] : stands for "extendedChars"(&4) along strolling through with its indexes([&3])
              },
              "@": "&4.&3[&2].&1"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
   // get rid of object labels
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: What if I have a request like shown below the output would be as 
`[
  {
    "id": "9164339966213408050",
    "extendedChars": [
      {
        "T BYOP T": {
          "values": [
            {
              "value": "60"
            }
          ],
          "name": "T BYOP T",
          "tomsId": "9162933742365468326"
        }, 
 "BYOP Tier": {
          "values": [
            {
              "value": "60"
            }
          ],
          "name": "BYOP T",
          "tomsId": "9162933742365468326"
      }
    ]
  }
]`

Comment: even once I have above one I need them to be separated in another extendedChars object
`    "name" : [ "T BYOP T", "BYOP T" ]`

Comment: Hi @NoOoNY , rather ask a new question please, this is a completed one. Sure I'll be following for `jolt` tag :) and be trying to solve it when I'm available.